# how to parse a class without executing it

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse my classes (which they are in separate files) and search for a specified variable or method, then if there was that variable so have to execute that.

I tried some ways:

1. I used to parse my files with preg_match seeking for some pattern.(not a good idea)
2. after that I try some code parser extension that was not good enough.
3. finally I tried `ArrayObject` class that it was not fine at all.(because it was parsing objects not classes)

is there any way to do that?

Pseudo-code:

```
$file = file_get_content("dir/myClassFile.php");
$classname='foo';
if(there was '$variable=x' in $classname)
    include "dir/myClassFile.php";
```

**edit**

file content:

```
class foo {
    var include = true; //1st

    function bar()
    {
        $this->include = true; //2nd 
    }
}
```

I need to check if include is ture then I have to include then file.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are looking for with `$variable = x`? Are you looking for the presence of a local variable, or a class property?  Please post a sample from a class that you want to retrieve, and what exactly you want to do with it. You can accomplish quite a lot [with `ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

Comment: That's a truly weird way to include a class... But if you must. Why not look/regex for `var/public/protected/private include = true;`? Sounds easy enough...

Comment: that is weird, yes. I want to check if classes has wanted var or method then include them.

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to *why* you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?  You should *already* know which of your classes contain `$include = true`, right?  Since you wrote them and put them there.  Unless these classes are coming from elsewhere... where are these classes coming from and why don't you know ahead of time which ones have `$include = true`?

Comment: So you need to literally inspect the default values of properties in a class. It is sorta possible to do this with `ReflectionClass::getProperty()` and [`ReflectionProperty::getValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) but that requires having already included and parsed the class. This is indeed an unusual approach. You can load them with `file_get_contents()` and `strpos()` the required strings, but that is going to be slower probably, than just including the classes to begin with.

Comment: yeah, but including them make some other problems. I should include parents too. take lots of ram. and maybe some conflict.

Comment: But you will have to read them all from disk as strings anyway to be able to inspect their contents. That's going to use loads of RAM too, especially if you are having to do it on every request --  it will never work with opcode caching (like APC, or PHP 5.5's built-in OpCache)

Comment: as I thought. it was sounds weird to me too.

Answer (score 1):

For simple syntax checking, using php on the command line goes a long way.  Simply call:

```
$ php -l <filename>
```

For more complex tools, check out Sebastian Bergmann's github. He is the author of phpunit, and has developed some really useful tools for detecting copy-pasted code, dead code, etc.

[Github Account](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann)

It would be a good idea to test your classes with PHPUnit, to make sure they function/work correctly.

There is also this [PHP Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/) that might come in use too.